# Should I Scale My Equation Output Data?

Tags: c#, equation, backpropagation, neural-network

With [this](http://home.agh.edu.pl/~vlsi/AI/backp_t_en/backprop.html) link i implemented a neural network to calculate `y=x*x`(x is input and y is output) equation.I 
took 1 unit in input layer,4 unit in hidden layer and 1 unit in output layer.
But When I enter for example `2` as input(so desired output is 4)
i got output value 0.99999999.... also this happens for all other input numbers bigger than 1(Its output is correct with value between 0 and 1).
also I used [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj658979.aspx) link and changed it to solve my equation,but the output was the same!

Comment: I guess source code would help to replicate your situation. From other hand, you could try to use AForge framework for this: http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/cc9202e0-a12b-3d55-85f0-0aa30fb48160.htm

Comment: thanks,i just want to know Is my number of NeuralNetwork layers and units in it is correct or not?

Comment: This shouldn't have been closed, I don't believe. The answer is that your network likely returns a result between 0 and 1. You need to train it to a scaled value. So, for example, you might need to set the potential range of x to be from 0 to 100. You would then multiply the result of the network by 100. Inputs also need to be scaled in a similar way. So, for example, if you value ranges are 0-100, then your input for 4 would actually be 0.04 and you would train the answer as 0.02. Or an input of 0.09 would train the answer as 0.03, etc. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Arash in a perceptron, "correct" is somewhat subjective; does it perform reasonably, when trained appropriately and tested against a separate validation set?

Comment: Someone should open this question back up. It's a perfectly legitimate question.

Comment: @Pete:thanks,i do not know understand your answer well.you mean the output value should be scale?the problem is with any number for input,the output is in 0.9999999.... range!

Comment: f(e) should be a cobb-douglas function, the product of the inputs to the w-th potency being w the current weight. And that's not a linear perceptron.

Comment: @Arash: Backprop neural networks generally operate on values of 0 to 1 or -1 to 1 for all inputs and outputs. That means you need to scale your inputs and outputs to fit in this range. You can't give an input of 4 and expect an output of 2. You need to scale your inputs and outputs so that they fit between a range of 0 and 1 (most likely, possibly -1 and 1, depending on the implementation).

Comment: @MarcGravell:thanks,i mean the number of layers and units in them.because i thought if layers of NN be more,it would find better answer

Comment: @Arash or maybe you'll just overfit the training data instead. Use a validation set to find out. More layers can be useful to fit more complex relationships, but that doesn't automatically mean "more layers === better"

Comment: @Pete:thanks for your answer,i should say that input value in this equation is for example 2 and i want to get something near 4.can you please show me by example?for example for input 2 i want something near 4,and for input 3 something near 9.and both output is 0.999999....so now how should i scale this?sorry for my misunderstanding

Comment: @Arash: http://www.faqs.org/faqs/ai-faq/neural-nets/part2/  - Go about 2/3 of the way down to the section titled: "Subject: Should I normalize/standardize/rescale the data?" Hopefully that will clarify. And I was mistaken. Your input doesn't need to be scaled, but your output does.

Comment: @MarcGravell:thanks,i got what you mean

Comment: You won't be able to fit a quadratic function with an MLP perfectly. You will only get a rough approxmiation with 4 hidden nodes. You could take a look at "higher order neural networks".

Comment: @alfa:thanks ,it is just a test to learn MLP & BP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Pete Said.I should normalize my output(and input) to get the correct answer.